# Dagster Installation on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python-3.x, macos, dagster

I am trying to install Dagster and Dagit using:`python3 -m pip install dagster dagit --user`
But, Always when it starts to build wheel for grpcio, it throws an error and stops the installation.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cb/vkzjvbbn2l5gbb31y3m61d_40000gp/T/pip-install-3005iws8/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cb/vkzjvbbn2l5gbb31y3m61d_40000gp/T/pip-install-3005iws8/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/cb/vkzjvbbn2l5gbb31y3m61d_40000gp/T/pip-record-8m4mi_rs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is anyone using Dagster and Dagit on Mac?

**EDIT: I was able to install Dagster by providing the required version in my requirements.txt File.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded the Pip to the latest version by`python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip` and then installed Dagster!
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The main installation steps for Dagster are outlined here: https://docs.dagster.io/getting-started/install#installation - however users with M1 Macs have run into issues recently (early 2023) related to `grpcio` package installation.

If you encounter that issue, you will need this command:

```
pip install dagster dagit --find-links=https://github.com/dagster-io/build-grpcio/wiki/Wheels
```